# Android Picasso load into Target sometimes not working

Tags: android, picasso

I have this code to load some images in the adapter. The problem is that most of time it works but sometimes the list was not displayed.

```
for (Product p: listItem) {
                Picasso.get().load( p.getBanner()).into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        bitmapList.add(bitmap);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I have used anonymous **Target** made the object eligible for garbage collection and sometimes it destroyed by **Garbage Collector**.